# What determines and confirms sensitivity of glaciers to climate change/ climate forcing?

Tags: climate-change, glaciology, climatology, glaciation

Consider two groups of glaciers, say Group A and Group B. For simplicity, let's consider the group to fall in one size class (say 1-5 sq km), both located in the same kind of climate. We DO NOT know the elevation (let's assume). If I have the retreat of Group A to be higher than Group B for the same period under warming temperatures, does that mean Group A is more sensitive to climate forcing?

Comment: Homework question?  If so, it's best to give some of your thinking on it.  You seem to have been active and perhaps asked deeper questions before, but at least give some motivation/background, as it comes off as a hw looking question to me at least

Comment: It does seem to be straightforward. Given the condition, since Group A shows the synchronous retreat, my immediate answer would be yes, Group A is more sensitive than group B. In other words, Group B is more resilient to the warming.
Now to make such a conclusion, I also need to know the elevation. If Group A tend to be located lower, again, the behaviour would be obvious.
However, when glacier slope is also taken into consideration, situation can be not so straightforward.
I have posted this question because the papers about sensitivity of glaciers seem little complicated to comprehend.